# Create new entity in node-wit

Tags: node.js, wit.ai

As per the wit documentation, in order to create a new entity for a particular Wit app using the HTTP ReST API is mentioned [here](https://wit.ai/docs/http/20170307#post--entities-link), is there any possible method to mimic the same using the node-wit module?

Answer (score 0):

Not currently, but you can just hit to REST API using something like the request module.